# On the geometry of quadra-coordinated coordination complexes

Tags: coordination-compounds

How do we tell whether a complex with a four coordinated central metal ion takes on a square planar geometry or a tetrahedral geometry?

Comment: Rough rule of thumb: if it's not d8 it's tetrahedral. If it's d8 and *not* nickel it's square planar. If it is nickel you either look it up, do the experiment or run the calculation. All assuming no steric constraints.

Comment: @Ian Bush. What do you mean with : If it is nickel, run the calculation !

Comment: @Maurice stick it in your favourite quantum chemistry package and run a geometry optimisation in both symmetries at the best level of theory you can afford. Select the one with the lowest energy.

Comment: I asked my teacher about it today. He said that for the first transition series elements, d⁹ and d¹⁰ configurations always form tetrahedral complexes, any other configuration is square planar under the influence of a strong field and tetrahedral under the influence of a weak field. For second and third transition series elements, all quadra coordinated complexes will be square planar